# How to use succinct circuits to construct an EXPTIME complete problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity, complexity-classes

When reasoning with NP-completeness, I find SAT and k-clique more convenient to reason with than generalized games that are NP-complete or the Turing machine model. I'm looking for something similar for EXPTIME-completeness. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME) mentions:

> Another set of important EXPTIME-complete problems relates to succinct
>   circuits. Succinct circuits are simple machines used to describe some
>   graphs in exponentially less space. They accept two vertex numbers as
>   input and output whether there is an edge between them. For many
>   natural P-complete graph problems, where the graph is expressed in a
>   natural representation such as an adjacency matrix, solving the same
>   problem on a succinct circuit representation is EXPTIME-complete,
>   because the input is exponentially smaller; but this requires
>   nontrivial proof, since succinct circuits can only describe a subclass
>   of graphs.[8]
>
> 8:  Papadimitriou (1994), section 20.1, page 492.

I understand the concept that you can describe some graphs using exponentially less space and use that as input, but I can't find the mentioned resource or find out how succinct graphs work exactly or how to construct an EXPTIME-complete problem.

Comment: You can find the book in any decent library.

Comment: Footnote 1 provides more details on the book. For example, its title is *Computational Complexity*. It is a pretty standard textbook.

Comment: I found that they have it in the University Library of Amsterdam. I'll drive there one of these days, thanks.

Comment: @AlbertHendriks you can find the book on the internet. pirate it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're having trouble getting hold of Papadimitriou's classic textbook *Computational Complexity*, let me suggest another resource: Papadimitriou's paper with Yannakakis, [A note on succinct representations of graphs](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995886800092). They prove the following general result:

> Suppose that $L$ is a P-complete problem, and that there is a polytime reduction $f$ from the Circuit Value Problem to $L$ in which, given an input $x_1\ldots x_n$ of size $n$, the $j$th bit of $f(x)$ is, *irrespective of $x$*, either constant of equals some input bit or its negation. Then the succinct version of $L$, which consists of pairs $\langle n,C \rangle$, where $C$ is a circuit on $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ inputs, such that $C(0) \ldots C(n-1) \in L$, is EXPTIME-complete.

The hard part of the proof uses the construction in the Cook–Levin theorem.